# Incorrect order items list

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, quote

When I need to change anything in quote from admin panel, I have to create new one and edit info there.

The problem is that when I create order based on the second quote, magento combines items list from both quotes and put into order. How can I fix this thing and make it to pull info only from the latest active quote?